# How to provide web access to interact with a file system?

Tags: web-server, file-sharing, web-applications, sshfs

I need to be able to provide web access to interact with a file system (upload/download files). In general people will access these files using sshfs but in a pinch we want people to have web access to these files. We want to run a web server, apache2, and some kind of web app or something on the file server which will allow people to log into the website and interact with the file system. If this web access was anything like dropbox that'd be great but it doesn't have to be nearly that slick. We just need upload and download capabilities.

We don't want to use WebDAV or SparkleShare.

Does anyone have any good recommendations for open source tools to do this or even some good web search keywords I could use to find it myself? So far I haven't found what I'm looking for because I don't really know what to look for.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you don't want to use webdav?

Comment: Accessing a WebDAV share through a web browser doesn't allow you to upload files. We would have to build the functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [alfresco](http://www.alfresco.org). It has a free community version. It's pretty advanced, e.g. it has versioning capabilities. It is java based. It has a big community and commercial support if you need it.

What I don't like about it though is that you whole filesystem that you want to share has to be transferred to an alfresco filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Why complicate things?  Consider setting up an FTP server as read-only with authentication.  Most popular web browsers in use are able to browse ftp sites and interact with them.

IMHO, you're asking for trouble if you allow file uploads via HTTP, because it becomes much easier for a malicious third-party to upload data that may compromised your server.  Website security is non-trivial, and prohibitively time-intensive for small organisations.

Comment: You lose a lot of credibility if you pretend to care about security and then suggest using FTP. ;-)

Comment: I did say read-only Graeme.  I was referring to the integrity of the of the server itself, not guaranteeing privacy during transmission - it's doubtful that caleban would be prepared to get a certificate for his web server.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at BarracudaDrive which combines a Web file Manager and WebDAV server.

The Web file Manager supports drag and drop upload in new browsers.

You will not find a server easier to use than this.

http://barracudaserver.com/products/BarracudaDrive/

You can download Linux,Win, Mac, etc versions, or use the automated online installer:
barracudaserver.com/products/BarracudaDrive/cloud/